# UIActivityIndicatorView weird behavior when stopping and starting

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a `UIViewController` and in its respective storyboard scene I have an activity indicator connect to the controller like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
```

I want to hide this activity indicator when the view is first launched, then after the users presses a button, inside its `@IBAction`, I want to start animating the indicator. So I wrote this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

and in my `@IBAction` I have:

```
@IBAction func attemptLogin(sender: UIButton) {    
    // Start the activity indicator
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

But this code does not work. The screen is launched without showing the activity indicator but when the button is pressed, it does not start animating and it does not even appear.

I have tried setting the `.hidden` property of this object but didn't get anywhere. I do not really want to add this indicator programmatically. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: You might also be interested in this class: https://github.com/goktugyil/CozyLoadingActivity

Answer (score 0):

**Try out dynamically create `UIActivityIndicatorView`**

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [spinner release];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you could consider here as the root of your  problems:

- The activity indicator is not attached to the IBOutlet
- The button's target is not attached to the IBAction (put a breakpoint in your method to be sure)
- The default state of an activity indicator is not animated, so your line: `activityIndicator.stopAnimating()` is redundant.
- Depending on your view's layouts/constraints, the UIActivityIndicator might be outside of your screens frame. Try printing out the activity indicators frame with `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(activityIndicator.frame))` before you start the animation.

Hope this helps!